# I dont understand recursive functions

Tags: recursion

Write a recursive function that computes the value of the recursively defined function 
F(n)= -F(n-2), F(0)=1 and F(1) = -2. Iv been staring at this for hours i don't understand. Thanks for help.

Comment: *To understand recursion you must first understand recursion* -- Anon.

Comment: Are you asking the community to do you homework ?? You should change your question in a way that reflects the problem you are facing.

Comment: smells like homework ;)

Comment: You are more likely to get help if you demonstrate that you've put at least some effort into solving this yourself.

Comment: What does this have to do with C++11?

Answer (score 1):

Like any programming problem, you can first express the solution using pseudo code, and then move on to implementing it in your language of choice, e.g.

```
FUNCTION F(n)
  IF n == 0           -- recursion terminates when n = 0, with result 0
    RETURN 0
  ELSE IF n == 1      -- recursion can also terminate when n = 1, with result -2
    RETURN -2
  ELSE                -- otherwise recursion contiunes with F(n - 2), F(n - 4), ...
    RETURN -F(n - 2)  -- until one of the terminating conditions is reached
END
```

From here it should be quite straightforward to implement this function in C++ or whatever language you choose. Be sure to also implement a "test harness", i.e. a function which calls `F` with a range of different input values and then prints the result, so that you can verify whether the function is behaving correctly and debug it if necessary.

Comment: (+1) Nice way to provide some direction without solving OP's homework.